# Reset styling for sub-component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a sub-component inside of an parent component.  The styling in the parent is incorrectly being applied to the sub-component, how do I reset it?

Specifically, I have a modal popup that get render inside a alert message:

[image]

This is the style in the parent:

```
<div class="slds-notification slds-notify_alert slds-alert_error slds-size_2-of-2" role="alert">
     Child component is rendered as part of the text inside here
</div>
```

Inside the child, the parent's alert styling is getting applied to all the modal text.  Text color is white so you can't see it, but it's there and also it apply center on text which you can seee.

[image]

What it should look like without parent's style interference.  As you can see it would just use the default normal salesforce font, and text is not centered.

[image]

Now I read in another question that I could use "all: initial;" to reset all the styling in the child component, I tried that but the problem is I lose the default Salesforce styling too:

[image]

My question is how do I remove the styling at just the parent level, can I move the entire modal to render outside of the parent div?  Or is there any other way to apply the default salesforce styling explicitly to overwrite the parent styling?

Here is the styling that's currently being applied to the children component text:

```
<h2 class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Request More Info</h2>
<p class="slds-var-m-top_x-small">Request more information on upgrading to the ... for Salesforce application</p>
```

Comment: I think you can try `color: initial` or check what Salesforce variable use by default for modal title text

Comment: but to be honest, I don't understand why you need to put modal inside popup, if visually they are not connected